# Endless permission on for another Linux user

Tags: centos7

I have a server with CentOS. I have there two web applications: the first one is a public application(with domain) and the second one is an admin panel for it(without domain).

Each application(public and admin) is difference Linux user. So admin panel application can manage the public application through DB and storage(remove/add files).

Now, I need to let the admin panel Linux user to manage public application storage.

What I do:

1. I created a group for these two Linux users(admin+publicApp) called GROUP
2. chgrp -R GROUP /path/for/public/app
3. chmod -R 2775 /path/for/public/app

After these actions adminApp can manage and "see" all files of public application. But it continues ~3 days. After 3 days adminApp cannot manage publicApp files again.

What is the problem and how make it endless?

Comment: Hi, Can you find more information regarding what happens after 3 days? Does the permission change? Are there any other processes running that coudl do this?

Comment: Hi @Tux_DEV_NULL.
The files/folders permissions change. I don't know why, I cannot handle the process which rolls is back(if there is any process), but when I run the last command(chmod) it works again

Comment: ok. I think we need more information. Does the permissions change for all files/folders or recent folders? Are there any other settings in place such as setuid? SeLinux?

Comment: I have no idea. Anyway thanks. Will update this question when I find the solution